# Binding IsReadOnly of a DataGridTextColumn to a DataGridTemplateColumn checkbox IsChecked

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

Basically, I have a `DataGrid` with several columns, and I want to enable (changing the `IsReadOnly` property) a `DataGridTextColumn` based on a `CheckBox` `IsChecked`, located in another `DataGridTemplateColumn` of the same `DataGrid`.

Here is (the important part of) the code:

```
<DataGrid Name="lstTags" Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path = LinesCollection}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" SelectionMode="Single" LostFocus="lstTags_LostFocus" SelectionChanged="lstTags_SelectionChanged">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="colAutoScale" Header="Auto Scale">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox x:Name="ckbAutoScale" HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding AutoScale, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                 </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Scale" Binding="{Binding Path=Scale}" IsReadOnly="{Binding ElementName ckbAutoScale, Path=IsChecked}" Width="60" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

It is worth mentioning that I also want to invert the value of the IsChecked property, that is

- `IsChecked = true` => `IsReadOnly = false`;
- `IsChecked = false` => `IsReadOnly = true`.

I would probably achieve this with a simple `Converter`, but I need that first part working tho.

EDIT:

Answering a good question, my goal is to **disable the adjacent cell** (same row), not the whole column.

Comment: you want to disable the whole column or adjacent cell??

Comment: Good point. The answer would be the adjacent cell. Come to think of it, the problem may be more complicate than I thought.

Comment: the simplest solution will be to bind the AutoScale property to Scale column's cell style's IsEnable property. please see my answer,I have given both UI dependent & Data dependent answer.

Comment: You may have to change to using a DataGridTemplateColumn and using data triggers to control what is shown in the CellEditTemplate if you are wanting to prevent editing on a cell by cell basis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below binding for your ***`Scale`*** `Column`:

```
 <DataGridTextColumn Header="Scale" Binding="{Binding Path=Scale}" Width="60" >
      <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
           <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridCellsPanel}},Path=Children[0].Content.Content.AutoScale}" />
           </Style>
      </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

***OR simply***

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Scale" Binding="{Binding Path=Scale}" Width="60" >
            <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding Path=AutoScale}" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
```

**Output:**

[image: ReadOnly]

> **PS:** Above Solution 1 is specific to your code, cause ***`Auto Scale`***
>   `column` is at **0** `Index` that's why I used `Children[0]` in
>   `Binding`. Please change if there is any contextual need.

Comment: Solution 2 satisfied my needs, simple and clean. Thank you!

Comment: @lucas.mdo yes, I would had preferred the same :)

Answer (score 3):

This type of problem is really the reason the [Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM) pattern](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/100175/Model-View-ViewModel-MVVM-Explained) exists.

With MVVM, you bind to view models that have the exact properties needed to support the view. This allows the model to be more concerned with what data needs to be persisted.

So, for your problem, you would need to create a `LineViewModel`, which would look something like this:

```
public class LineViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private bool _isAutoScale;
    private double _scale;

    public bool IsAutoScale
    {
        get { return _isAutoScale; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _isAutoScale) return;
            _isAutoScale = value;
            OnPropertyChange("IsAutoScale");
            OnPropertyChange("IsReadOnly");
        }
    }

    public double Scale
    {
        get { return _scale; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _scale) return;
            _scale = value;
            OnPropertyChange("Scale");
        }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly => !IsAutoScale;

    private void OnPropertyChange(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Meanwhile, you would also want to create a parent view model called `MainWindowViewModel` (or something that makes sense for your situation). Here is a very crude version:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private List<LineViewModel> _lineViewModels;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public List<LineViewModel> LineViewModels
    {
        get { return _lineViewModels; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _lineViewModels) return;
            _lineViewModels = value;
            OnPropertyChange("LineViewModels");
        }
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        LineViewModels = new[]
        {
            new { AutoScale = false, Scale = 0.2 },
            new { AutoScale = true, Scale = 0.3 },
            new { AutoScale = false, Scale = 0.4 },
        }
            .Select(
                x => new LineViewModel
                {
                    IsAutoScale = x.AutoScale,
                    Scale = x.Scale
                })
            .ToList();
    }

    private void OnPropertyChange(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Finally, you would update your XAML file to look something like this:

```
<Window x:Class="Sandbox.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:sandbox="clr-namespace:Sandbox"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="350"
        Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <sandbox:MainWindowViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding LineViewModels}"
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              CanUserAddRows="False"
              CanUserDeleteRows="False"
              SelectionMode="Single">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Auto Scale">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                  IsChecked="{Binding IsAutoScale}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Auto Scale">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Scale}"
                                 IsReadOnly="{Binding IsReadOnly}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Window>
```

So, basically, the view logic for `MainWindow` is determined by `MainWindowViewModel` and the view logic for each row of the `DataGrid` is controlled by a `LineViewModel`.

Note that a lot of the boilerplate for implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` can be simplified using libraries/NuGet packages like MVVM Light Toolkit and PropertyChanged.Fody.

Comment: I do use the MVVM pattern and I do have both ViewModels you are suggesting. Still, I couldn't make it to work the way I wanted, maybe because I was trying to avoid using DataGridTemplateColumn for Scale.