# DataGrid isReadyOnly not working properly

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a dataGrid where `isReadOnly` is set to `true`. Inside that dataGrid, I have multiple columns (DataGridTemplateColumn), the one that I'm facing issues with is this one:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn IsReadOnly="True" SortMemberPath="OnVacation" Header="En vacance" >                                               <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
<CheckBox  VerticalAlignment="Center"  IsChecked="{Binding Path=OnVacation, Mode=TwoWay}"  />
    </DataTemplate>
  </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I have also set `sReadyOnly` in the column itself (as you can see above) but that didn't do anything. I can still check/uncheck the CheckBox and It will change.

Comment: any specific reason for `Mode=TwoWay`  for CheckBox

Comment: @un-lucky I just copy pasted from another line I made and forgot to remove it, no reason. Either way, removing it won't do much.

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36650502/binding-isreadonly-of-a-datagridtextcolumn-to-a-datagridtemplatecolumn-checkbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you permanently want to keep checkbox not changeable by the user then you can use

**1. IsEnabled="False"**

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn IsReadOnly="True" SortMemberPath="OnVacation" Header="En vacance" >
 <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
   <CheckBox  VerticalAlignment="Center"  IsChecked="{Binding Path=OnVacation, 
   Mode=TwoWay}" IsEnabled="False"  />
  </DataTemplate>
 </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

**2. IsHitTestVisible="False"**

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn IsReadOnly="True" SortMemberPath="OnVacation" Header="En vacance">
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <CheckBox  VerticalAlignment="Center"  IsChecked="{Binding Path=OnVacation, Mode=TwoWay}" IsHitTestVisible="False">
                                        </CheckBox>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: That will leave me with a greyed checkbox though. I don't want that.

Comment: then you should prepare a style for checkbox to show normal even when disabled.